# How to search an Event to get the name of an Element?

Tags: html, typescript, dom

Lets say I have a clipboard paste event inside my component like below.

```
window.addEventListener('paste', this.insertNewRowsBeforePaste.bind(this));
```

Then when I hit the ctrl + V on my keyboard it calls this event which is a ClipboardEvent

```
insertNewRowsBeforePaste(event) {   
const tabName = // <---- I need to be able to see which tab the user has clicked on then I can do other processing based on the current tab.
}
```

So I'm expecting it to say tabName = 'Tab 1' or 'Tab 2' etc since my component is a tab control with multiple tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) `event.target` will provide the [HTMLElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) that triggered the event. You can then target the [name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/name) property on elements such as `<button>`, `<input>`, and `<a>`. You also have access to additional properties such as `innerHTML` and `textContent` to check against.

```
insertNewRowsBeforePaste(event) {   
    const target = event.target;
    const name = target.name; 

    console.log(name);

    if (name.indexOf('Tab 1') > -1) { console.log('Tab 1'); }
}
```

Here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/355pmzyt/27/) using `event.target` of a clicked elements to access their respective `name`, `innerHTML` and `textContent` property values.

If you are doing this in TypeScript, you will need to use casting/type-assertion on the `target` to access `HTMLButtonElement | HTMLInputElement | HTMLAnchorElement`  properties such as `name`:

```
insertNewRowsBeforePaste(event) {
    const target = event.target as HTMLButtonElement;
    const name = target.name;

    // or
    // const name = (<HTMLButtonElement> event.target).name;

    // or
    // const target = event.target as HTMLButtonElement;
    // const { name } = target;        
}
```

Hopefully that helps!